# How to print out a 2d list that is formatted into a grid?

Tags: python, list, 2d

Currently, I have made this code

```
def grid_maker(h,w):
    grid = [[["-"] for i in range(w)] for i in range(h)]
    grid[0][0] = ["o"]
    print grid

>>>grid_maker(3,5) => [[['o'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']], [['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']], [['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']]]
```

I want to make another function that will take in the produced 2d array and print it out such that it is in this format:

```
o----
-----
-----
```

However, I am unsure where to start.

Comment: Any specific reason you have the characters inside one element lists?

Comment: This program is for an assignment. Basically, we are to generate a grid with dimension that the user inputs. The user then can move the o around the grid. I had made the program such that it will work with manipulating a list inside a list.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to "pretty" print your grid with each sublist on its own line, you can use [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html):

```
>>> grid=[[['o'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']], [['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']], [['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']]]

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(grid)

[[['o'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']],
 [['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']],
 [['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-']]]
```

It will still show each element as a list, as you defined it, if you want to show them as strings you'll have to use joins like m.wasowski suggests.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the result of `grid_maker()`, you have to return its result, using `return`:

```
def grid_maker(h, w):
    grid = [["-" for i in range(w)] for i in range(h)]
    grid[0][0] = "o"
    return grid
```

I modified it, because I don't think that each element must be inside another `list`.

To print the "grid", you could iterate through each *row* and then iterate through each element:

```
def print_grid(grid):
    for row in grid:
        for e in row:
            print e,
        print
```

**Output:**

```
print_grid(grid_maker(3, 5))

o - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
```

Comment: I consider your solution prior but ran into the trouble that my program had to keep them as a 2d array.

Comment: In fact my solution is a 2D array. Yours is a 3D array.

Comment: @user3225528 A list `[1,2]` is 1D. A list `[[1,2],[3,4]]` is 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Use string join()

```
for row in grid:
    print ''.join(*zip(*row))
```

or as one-liner:

```
print '\n'.join(''.join(*zip(*row)) for row in grid)
```

but if would rather recommend you to change everything into:

```
def grid_maker(h,w):
    grid = [["-" for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h)]
    grid[0][0] = "o"
    return grid

print '\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in grid_maker(5,5))
```

Comment: when I tried to implement your code it only printed off the first column

Comment: corrected. Got mislead by those nested (unecessary) lists. `*zip(*row)` is python idiom for 'flattening' `row`.

Comment: Nice! I'll personally play around *zip(*row) to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: I've added for you version without unecessary nesting